# Use an normal image as iconbackground from an svg file

Tags: php, svg, background, effect

is it possible with php (or js/css) to change the background from an SVG (by using an normal image) and convert it to an png?

**Example**
 [image: demo]

Comment: Yes, it is. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: This demo-image is created with Photoshop oO

Comment: You can use a clip-path to obtain such a result.